# How to define a function which returns a map

Tags: function, dictionary, go

I am attempting to define a function which returns an initialized map:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"

func defaults() map {
  m := make(map[string]string)
  m["start"] = "1"
  m["from"]  = "encrypted"
  m["to"]    = "loaded"
  return m
}

func main() {
  args := os.Args[1:]
  fmt.Println(args)
  runvals := defaults()
  fmt.Println(runvals)
}
```

Errors I'm getting:

```
Line 6 col 21 error| expected '[', found '{'
Line 7 col 5 error| expected ']', found ':='
Line 11 col 3 error| expected declaration, found 'return'
```

Can someone help me get the syntax right? Or am I trying to do something that Go doesn't do?

Comment: It's not your question, but `return map[string]string{"start": "1", "from": "encrypted", "to": "loaded"}` is easier (and more efficient) than creating a map and then assigning items one by one.

Comment: If you know the size of map in advance, you can pass the size as the second parameter to make. https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#make

Comment: Many thanks to all, both for your information and for your kindness to a newbie! I've learned quite a lot about Go this week, and very much appreciate the boost you've given me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func defaults() map[string] string {
    m := make(map[string]string)
    m["start"] = "1"
    ...
    return m
}
```

The problem with your defaults function is the return type map has no types.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the whole type including key and value types.

```
func defaults() map[string]string {
    …
}
```

Comment: Got it! THANK YOU! Fixed my code and learned something ... definition of a good day!